# XNA/MonoGame RenderTargets not working

Tags: xna, c#, monogame

I'm having a problem with drawing 2 RenderTargets to the screen.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;

namespace Please
{
    class Class1
    {
        RenderTarget2D rt;
        Texture2D temp;
        Vector2 v;
        public Class1(Vector2 v,GraphicsDevice g)
        {
            this.v = v;
            rt=new RenderTarget2D(g,800,600);
        }

        public void Draw(SpriteBatch sb,GraphicsDevice gd,ContentManager cm)
        {
            gd.SetRenderTarget(rt);
            sb.Begin();
            sb.Draw(cm.Load<Texture2D>("Untitled.png"),v,Color.White);
            sb.End();
            gd.SetRenderTarget(null);

            temp = (Texture2D)rt;

            sb.Begin();
            sb.Draw(temp, Vector2.Zero, Color.White);
            sb.End();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my draw function in the actual "game"

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
    base.Draw(gameTime);
    one.Draw(spriteBatch, graphics.GraphicsDevice, Content);
    two.Draw(spriteBatch, graphics.GraphicsDevice, Content);
}
```

one and two have positions (100,200) and (300,200) respectively, so, they should be drawn 100 pixels apart, however, only two is being drawn with the rest of the screen black

[image: The problem]

Answer (score 2):

Clear both rt's to Transparent before drawing the texture to them.

Since you will be explicitly clearing them to Transparent[Black], you should specify:

```
 new RenderTarget2D(..., RenderTargetUsage.PreserveContents);
```

to prevent XNA from clearing rt's rendertarget (to **not** Transparent[Black]) when you set the current rendertarget to NULL.

When you draw them with AlphaBlending enabled (the default), the **not** Transparent[Black] overwrites the backbuffer, as though you were using Opaque.

**Also:**
You should not Load<> the texture more than once and it should be during or after game.LoadContent(). You are currently re-re-re-re-re-loading it every time you render it.

Comment: I think re-re-re-re-re-loading textures is actually fine, since the ContentManager caches its result causing the texture to be loaded from disk only on first load.